# So I want to stop the program in a certain situation

Tags: javascript

So let's say I want to make the code stop..

```
var test = "good";

if (test === "good") {
    alert("The test is good");
}
else if (test ==="bad") {
    alert("Oh no, the test went bad!");
```

what do I put here so that if the test is bad, the code will stop completely and it won't alert you on passing the test

```
}

alert("You've passed the test");
```

Again, this is an example, not the actual project I'm working on, but what do I do?

Comment: Simply add `return;`

Comment: Is code within a function? Why is `alert("You've passed the test");` outside of `if..else..if`?

Comment: But I don't want to return it, I just want it to stop the code and not continue on to whatever Is next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `exit();` That should work for you.